# MySQLi not returning rows in order

Tags: php, mysqli

This is probably not a very difficult question to answer. I'm having trouble with this PHP function I wrote... it returns the rows line by line, but it's returning them incremented by 4 each time. So the the 1st row will output, then the 5th, then the 9th...

```
function showDatabases() {

# $_GET variables from the URL.
$database = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['database']);
$table    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['table']);   

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', $database);

$query_one = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from $table");

$num_rows   = mysqli_num_rows($query_one);
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($query_one);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $num_rows; $x++) {
       for ($c = 0; $c < $num_fields; $c++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query_one);
            echo($row[$c]."&nbsp;&nbsp;");
       }
    echo("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that your `mysql_real_escape_string` does not protect your query; you'd better check against a whitelist of allowed table names. Apart from that it will not do anything at all as you need a database connection for the function to be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_row` fetched an entire row and moves the pointer to the following row. You should call it only once per each row; now you are calling it once per column.

That is,

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $num_rows; $x++) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query_one);
   for ($c = 0; $c < $num_fields; $c++) {
        echo($row[$c]."&nbsp;&nbsp;");
   }
echo("<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Joni. I appreciate your answer. I was wondering why my rows weren't outputting correctly!

Answer (score 0):

you are complicating things 
you can do it with just one loop

```
$query = "SELECT * from $table";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['fieldname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

I advice you to add order by some time the default order is not the id order.